# Projective Resolution of $C[x,y,t]/(x^2+y^2-t)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, projective-module, free-modules

I need to find a free projective resolution of $\mathbb{C}[x,y,t]/(x^2+y^2-t)$ as a $\mathbb{C}[t]$-module.  A projective resolution of an $R$-module $M$ is a long exact sequence 
$$...\rightarrow P_n\rightarrow P_{n-1}\rightarrow...\rightarrow P_0\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0.$$  Here each $P_i$ is required to be a projective $R$-module (hence the name).  I require a free resolution, so the $P_i$ must be free as $C[t]$-modules.  I can do simple examples, such as projective resolutions of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$ module, i.e
$$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\rightarrow 0.$$

I can do slightly harder example as well, but am at a loss whenever it comes to more complex examples.  It would be a great help if some one could describe a projective resolution of this $R$-module, and even better if they could give some general techniques for tackling these sorts of questions.

Note: This is not a homework question, but rather me trying to understand some algebraic geometry machinery, and this came up in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\Bbb C [x,y,t] $ is a free $\Bbb C [t] $-module, hence we have a free resolution over $\Bbb C [t] $:
$$\{0\}\to\Bbb C [x,y,t]\to\Bbb C [x,y,t]\to\Bbb C [x,y,t]/\langle x^2+y^2-t\rangle\to\{0\} $$
where the first map is the multiplication by $x^2+y^2-t $, while the second is the canonical projection.

Comment: Oh, of course!  Multiplication by the prime ideal (x^2+y^2-t), so it is very similar to forming a projective resolution of Z/2 over Z.

Comment: This situation arise with quotients by principal ideals.